# Excel: How do i construct nested If condition in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is an grading formula based on the score.

```
If score < 4 Then LEVEL 1
If score > 4 and score < 9 LEVEL 2
If score > 8 and score < 13 LEVEL 3
If score > 12 and score < 15 LEVEL 4
If score > 15 LEVEL 5
```

I really could not figure out, Where is the mistake. Please help.

```
=IF(A1<4,"LEVEL 1",IF(AND(A1>4,A1<9),"LEVEL 2",IF(AND(A1>8,A1<13,"LEVEL 3",IF(AND(A1>12,A1<17,"LEVEL 4",IF(A1>16,"LEVEL 5")))))))
```

Comment: 4th level is <17 and 5th level is >15?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I corrected the mistake.

Comment: I am assuming the levels are <4, 4-7,8-11,12-14,15 and above. If this is right, I have a simpler formula =min(int(A1/4)+1, 5)

Comment: ="Level "&min(int(A13/4)+1, 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your `AND`'s in the right before the then conditions.
The third `IF` ended up having a huge condition and no then or else statement, this happened with the last `AND` too.

```
=IF(A1<4,              "LEVEL 1",
 IF(AND(A1>4, A1<9),   "LEVEL 2",
 IF(AND(A1>8, A1<13),  "LEVEL 3",
 IF(AND(A1>12, A1<17), "LEVEL 4",
 IF(A1>16,             "LEVEL 5")))))
```

Comment: Brilliant.  It worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `AND()`. If 1st condition doesn't pass automatically number is greater than 4 thus you just check if it is lower that 9 and so on...
Or in a formula:

```
=IF(A1<4,"LEVEL 1",IF(A1<9,"LEVEL 2",IF(A1<13,"LEVEL 3",IF(A1<17, "LEVEL 4", "LEVEL 5"))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Today i learned something on the excel formula

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, you just need to make sure you close off the brackets for the `AND` statements:

```
=IF(A1<4,"LEVEL 1",IF(AND(A1>4,A1<9),"LEVEL 2",IF(AND(A1>8,A1<13),"LEVEL 3",IF(AND(A1>12,A1<17),"LEVEL 4",IF(A1>16,"LEVEL 5")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got it working, but there's another approach you might want to consider rather than nested IFs in a situation like this.

Create a table on another sheet or elsewhere on your sheet with your levels and the score needed to reach them:
0   Level 1
4   Level 2
8   Level 3
12  Level 4
15  Level 5

Then use a VLOOKUP or an INDEX(MATCH function to find matches. I like the INDEX(MATCH since it gives you more control.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,1))
```

In this case, our list would be on Sheet1, with the Levels listed in column B and the required scores in column A, while our formula is on sheet 2 referencing actual scores that start in A1.

The `INDEX` function looks at an array - B1:B5 - and returns a value from a specified row in that array. The `MATCH` function looks at an array - A1:A5 - and returns the location in the array of the highest number that is less than or equal to the match value. It passes this result back to the `INDEX` so it can select the appropriate row.

This method is easier to maintain, modify and expand than a multi-level nested `IF`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this formula:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(Score,{0,4,8,12,15},1),"Level 1","Level 2","Level 3","Level 4","Level 5")
```

Score is a defined name to the cell of your input.